# Can some hackers hack my CFBundleDisplayName?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building an iOS app with two targets (Free and Paid) because they both have the same code but with little changes such as iAd...etc

In code, I am distinguishing between these targets using this line of code:

```
IsFree = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"] isEqualToString:@"Game.Free"];
```

I am worried if the infoDictionary file is vulnerable to hackers (jailbreak or something).

Is there a better way to distinguish between the targets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more standard approach for this is to use compiler directives.

In the build settings for your two targets, edit the "Other C Flags" setting. For the "Lite" version target, add something like:

> -DLITE_VERSION

For the paid version target, add something like:

> -DPAID_VERSION

Then when you have code that is specific to the "lite" version you can do:

```
#ifdef LITE_VERSION
    // Lite version specific code here
#endif
```

And for any code specific to the paid version, you can do:

```
#ifdef PAID_VERSION
    // Paid version specific code here
#endif
```